# React Router, Page Not Found handling

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have this setup for my routes:

```
             <Container>
                <Input />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={LatestMovies}/>
                    <Route path='/movie/:id' component={MovieWithDetails}/>
                    <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </Container>
```

1.How would I need to setup the router, so that the `Input` component would be visible with all other components inside the `Switch`, except for the `PageNotFound` component?

I know that I could add the `Input` component inside the other components manually, but was wondering if there was a better way?

2.Inside the `MovieWithDetails` component I'm using fetch, where I fetch for a movie with an id, which I get from clicking on a link from the `LatestMovies` component through the router props.

The link, and any id can also be manually typed, so I was wondering, how would I need to handle the showing of `PageNotFound` component here?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Did you try with multiple  components? Something like:

```
<Switch>
        <Input/>
        <Route path='/' exact component={LatestMovies}/>
        <Route path='/movie/:id' component={MovieWithDetails}/>
</Switch>

<Switch>
<Route path='/somepath' component={PageNotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

2 - I think that it's subjective. In my opinion I would show a feedback saying that there's no movie with the typed ID and I would not redirect to the PageNotFound component. But if you want to do it, with a simple `this.props.history.push('/somepath') will be right